# Point domain names to different wildcard subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain, cpanel

I have a multi user web app that assigns a subdomain to every user upon registration. The server is configured to accept wildcard subdomains and every subdomain request retrieves data related the the subdomain owner.

I want my users to be able to purchase domain names and use in place of their subdomain names.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this your own server or is that website on a hosting server?

Comment: It is on a hosting server.

Comment: Then I doubt what you wanna do is allowed. Please ask them if it's possible and how.

Comment: What kind of server do you recommend and how would it work?

Comment: They perhaps could use a CNAME record to map their domain name to your alias?: `bar.example.net.        CNAME  foo.example.com`.  But there is a restriction on CNAMEing root domains.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I am still looking out for a way to get this done. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is far too broad (if you have more details to add, do not put them in comments but edit your initial post) and too simple in its most generic sense. Your users will just go to any domain name registrar, buy a name, and configure their domains to point to your nameservers (or using other nameservers to point relevant records to your IP addresses, using a CNAME trick like @Progrock says except for the apex)